# How to put two <div> in a row? If I use inline block, the first div does down to bottom

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="border:1px solid gold;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:10%;">
    10:30am
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the "10:30am" to be on top the same row with "Name"

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) with `display:flex;`:

```html
<div style="display:flex;border:1px solid gold;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right: 0.5rem;border:1px solid red;width:10%;">
    10:30am
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```html
<div style="border:1px solid gold;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:10%;vertical-align:top">
    10:30am
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just added `vertical-align:top`

*EDIT:* if you want it to be in the middle then just use `vertical-align:middle` on both `div`

```html
<div style="border:1px solid gold;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:10%;vertical-align:middle">
    10:30am
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;vertical-align:middle">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I wanna know, if I want the 10:30am to middle, where "Test x t" is, how should I do?

Comment: So,  when vertical-align: top is applied to left div, it goes up to top. Why I need to apply vertical-align: middle on both (if I just apply it on to left div, it does not work)? so it goes to middle?

Comment: @JeremyLee, because using `vertical-align: top` they already know they will just go to the top or bottom, but in the middle, they need some setting, setting `vertical-align: middle` alone on the left `div` will be confusing like *middle of what?*, so we add another alignment to the right.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.time{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  font-size:34px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.details{
  background-color: lightblue;
  font-size:24px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.time, .details{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="time">
    10:30am
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Just add** `vertical-align:top;` css to your structure.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid gold;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;width:10%;vertical-align:top;">
    10:30am
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
    <div>Test × t</div>
  </div>
</div>
```